# sound never worked on Lubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: sound, lubuntu, alsa

thanks for your help, i have tried to solve my problem for weeks to no avail.
The only way for me to have sound was to plug in earphones. Unfortunately i do not have them anymore.

This is a pc I made of different parts i bought. My only output device was a [Hyperx Cloud headset](https://www.hyperxgaming.com/us/headsets/cloud-gaming-headset) which is not working anymore.
Operating system:  Lubuntu
Graphics : Radeon rx 580 dual oc 8GO
processor : Ryzen 5 2600
MotherBoard : asRock B450 pro4

My screen is a dell **P2210** one, it doesn't seem to have outside sound.
I just plugged in ordinary earphones which work, but I need louder sound; perhaps I should buy a set of external speakers?

Here are several output, I'm not sure about how to read them
Output for 
`sudo lshw -c sound` :

```
 *-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       produit: Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]
       fabriquant: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       identifiant matériel: 0.1
       information bus: pci@0000:26:00.1
       version: 00
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       ressources: irq:68 mémoire:fe960000-fe963fff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       produit: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
       fabriquant: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       identifiant matériel: 0.3
       information bus: pci@0000:28:00.3
       version: 00
       bits: 32 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       ressources: irq:70 mémoire:fe800000-fe807fff
```

Output for 
`lspci` :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 59)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
03:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller (rev 01)
03:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset SATA Controller (rev 01)
03:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Bridge (rev 01)
1d:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
1d:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
1d:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
1d:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
1d:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
1d:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
22:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
24:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
25:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
26:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (rev e7)
26:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]
27:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Raven/Raven2 PCIe Dummy Function
27:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor
27:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin USB 3.0 Host controller
28:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Renoir PCIe Dummy Function
28:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
28:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
```

Output for 
`aplay -l` :

```
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels PLAYBACK ****
carte 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], périphérique 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], périphérique 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], périphérique 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], périphérique 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], périphérique 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], périphérique 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], périphérique 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
```

Output for 
`lsb_release -a` :

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

When using pavucontrol, i can set sound going up and down but i have never heard it.

What can i do now ? I feel desperate

Thanks for any help

(pavucontrol image there)
[pavucontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30ViA.png)

Comment: What is the model number of the Dell monitor? Some monitors with HDMI do have speakers.

Comment: Apologies, I bought a new set of speakers and the sound is doing great